# Can not import front end code

Tags: javascript, html, django, reactjs

My Django project has the following structure:

[image]

I am displaying `questions.html` in the browser:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
  Questions:

  <div id="questionSpace"></div>

  <script src="../js/frontEnd/src/App.js"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

`questions.html` is referencing the code from `App.js` which is:

```
import {React, Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/questions`)
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({questions: result.json()})
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.questions.map(question => <li>question.content</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("questionSpace"));
```

For some reason, the javascript code is not included in the html page.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Have you [checked your console for errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) Are you preprocessing that code at all? React uses JSX which isn't natively supported in browsers and `import` is not supported in most browsers yet. Your code needs to be compiled.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you may want to use [`<script ...></script>` instead of `<script ... />`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Second of all, if you use JSX and/or ES6 (e.g. the `import` syntax), you want to compile those first, then include the compiled .js in the page, not the source JSX.

Finally, if `questions.html` is rendered as a Django template, including `<script src="../js/frontEnd/src/App.js"></script>` wouldn't work unless you setup Django to [serve static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/), e.g. on `/static/`

```
  <script src="/static/js/frontEnd/dist/App.js"></script>
```

Notice above I use `dist/App.js` instead of `src/App.js` to emphasize that you will eventually need a compiled .js